# jquery buttons do not align properly

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

Does anyone know how to align these jquery buttons without using `float:left`?

This problem occurs when `<button>` and any other elements like `<a>` are used:

http://jsbin.com/afixij/edit#javascript,html,live

Same problem is also on jquery's website:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't have this issue before, so I checked my old codes using older versions of jquery-ui. I noticed that old `.ui-button` class had `overflow:visible` instead of `overflow:hidden` Changed it to `overflow:visible`, voila it's fixed.

Comment: Congrads :p Gotta love those abstract css tags that give you all sorts of weird behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

It's because the class `.ui-button` in `jquery-ui.css` is using `display: inline-block;`

[image]

The problem goes away if you change that to `display: inline-table;`

[image]

Comment: `display: inline-table` is a Table model values. Not sure it is good to use in this scenario.

Comment: ? See http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp, the purpose of `display: inline-table` is to display elements as an inline-table, which is perfect when you have something like a series of buttons you want displayed in alignment with each other. `inline-block` places the element as an inline element (on the same line as adjacent content), but it behaves as a block element - which is the problem here since when rendered visually, block-level elements usually begin on a new line. (See http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/block.html)

Comment: after change, chrome does the same thing :(

Comment: Well I hope you'll consider an upvote on an answer that works for ie 7+ and firefox. Honestly, you're always going to run into CSS problems when you're using someone else's hugely complicated CSS libraries and trying to get the same behaviour on all browsers. I recommend dialing back on the number of styles inherited. If you want a workaround, do what display: inline-table is supposed to do - just place your elements in a table: http://jsbin.com/afixij/3/edit